# Como adicionar essa "barrinha" acima do menu? HTML+CSS

Tags: html, css

**Como adicionar uma barrinha igual a que o Stackoverflow tem no topo acima do menu? Sei que parece ser uma pergunta bem ignorante da minha parte porém eu encontro muita dificuldade em HTML e CSS!**

[image: 1]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É somente um `border-top`:

```css
html, body { margin: 0 }

header {
  border-top: 3px solid #F48024;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px #ccc;
  height: 40px
}
```

```html
<header></header>
```